# JPA Hibernate, returen statement caused lazy-loading to load

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

the return statement of below function caused lazy loading to load. When I changed return Orderbean to return null or lazy to eager. at the return statement it still went to query DB. please help me out, what caused this, thanks.

OrderBean is created and initialized inside the function, OrderBean and Area are not related.

```
   @Transactional
        public OrderBean create(){
        function(){
            .
            .
            function(){
                ProductCustom custom=productCustomDao.findByProductAndArea(area,product);
                OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem();
                //product.getThumbnail() caused this, but product's attribute thumbnail has no relation with Area. 
                orderItem.setThumbnail(custom!=null?custom.getThumbnail():product.getThumbnail());
            }
            .
            . 

        }
        return OrderBean;
    }

    Area:
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        @JoinTable(name = "xinyunlian_organization_area", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "areas"))
        public Organization getOrganization() {
            return organization;
        }

       Organization:
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "xinyunlian_organization_area", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "organization"))
        public Set<Area> getAreas() {
            return areas;
        }

ProductCustom:
@Column(nullable = false)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "xinyunlian_product_custom_area", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_custom_id"))
    public Set<Area> getAreas() {
        return areas;
    }
```

Hibernate: select area0_.id as id15_0_, area0_.create_date as create2_15_0_, area0_.modify_date as modify3_15_0_, area0_.orders as orders15_0_, area0_.a_code as a5_15_0_, area0_.full_name as full6_15_0_, area0_.gb_code as gb7_15_0_, area0_.name as name15_0_, area0_.name_path as name9_15_0_, area0_.number_type as number10_15_0_, area0_.order_type as order11_15_0_, area0_.parent as parent15_0_, area0_.promotion_number as promotion12_15_0_, area0_.tree_path as tree13_15_0_, area0_1_.organization as organiza1_16_0_ from xinyunlian_area area0_ left outer join xinyunlian_organization_area area0_1_ on area0_.id=area0_1_.areas where area0_.id=?

Comment: where is OrderBean defined and initialized? How is OrderBean related to Organization or Area related to it? Can you rephrase your question, not sure it is clear.

Comment: if a getter method is being called then obviously the field has to be LOADED

Comment: why is it loaded at the return statement?